# Magento 2 : Swatches not display when use plugin around

Tags: magento2, product, plugin, around-plugin

I used around plugin to call custom phtml in category list page. It's working proper. But, In configurable product it's hide to display swatches.

I upload here my files code. Which function should I need to use in plugin to working perfectly ?

**di.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="custom-module-category" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\File" sortOrder="16"/>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="custom-module-search" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\File" sortOrder="17"  />
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**File.php :**

```
public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
    $data = $this->_productDocFactory->create()->load($product->getId(), 'product_id');
    if(count($data->getData())){
    return $this->layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\File')->setProduct($data_id)->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::file.phtml')->toHtml();
    } else {
    return '';
    }
    }
```

Comment: Where you have defined and set value for `$data_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't anything in else condition. So, it was display blank. Use this below code :

```
 public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
) {
    $data = $this->_producyFactory->create()->load($product->getId(), 'product_id');
    if (count($data->getData())) {
        return $this->layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\File')->setProduct($data)->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::file.phtml')->toHtml();
    } else {
        $result = $proceed($product);
        return $result;
    }
}
```